# C# object instance not working properly

Tags: c#, reference, instance

I have a class *Node* as below:

```
public class Node
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> dictionary; 
    public Node(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }
    public void CreateNode()
    {
        this.dictionary.Add("1", "String1");
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Console.WriteLine(this.dictionary["1"]);
        Node tmp = new Node(dictionary1);
        tmp.dictionary = this.dictionary;
        Console.WriteLine(tmp.dictionary["1"]);
        tmp.AddE(tmp, "String2","2");

        Console.WriteLine(this.dictionary["2"]);
    }
    public void AddE(Node tmp,String text,string c)
    {
        tmp.dictionary.Add(c,text);
    }               
}
```

*Node* has a dictionary with string key and value, a constructor with parameter, a method *CreateNode()* which adds an item to dictionary and creates another *Node*. Now, after *tmp.dictionary = this.dictionary;* another item is added at *tmp.dictionary* but also it's added at *this.dictionary* (I don't want that to happen, I'm missing smth).

Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Node n = new Node(dictionary);
    n.CreateNode();
}
```

Output is:

```
String1
String1
String2
```

For this line of code *Console.WriteLine(this.dictionary["2"]);* it should show this error *KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.* because I didn't add an item with key "2" at *this.dictionary*. Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Your code is *really* obfuscated. The fact that you've got two different dictionaries involved, and that you've got an instance method in `Node` which accepts another `Node` but doesn't do anything with the target of the method invocation is confusing things massively.

Comment: Asteam please do not add answer into question - if you think existing answers didn't solve problem post your own answer as separate answer

Comment: And just code wouldn't really be an answer to why you're seeing the current behaviour anyway...

Answer (score 7):

> because I didn't add an item with key "2" at this.dictionary.

Yes you did. You did it with this call:

```
tmp.AddE(tmp, "String2","2");
```

That adds an entry with key "2" and value "String2" to the dictionary referred to by `tmp`... which is the same dictionary that `this` refers to due to this line:

```
tmp.dictionary = this.dictionary;
```

The second dictionary that you created with the line:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

... is eligible for garbage collection, because nothing refers to it afterwards. It's *initially* the dictionary in the new `tmp` node, but then you replace that with the reference to the same dictionary in "this", as shown above.

Side-note: try to avoid constructing such confusing code. A method like this is a recipe of problems:

```
public void AddE(Node tmp,String text,string c)
{
    tmp.dictionary.Add(c,text);
}
```

That's an *instance* method, but it doesn't use any of the state of the "current" instance (that `this` refers to) - instead, it modifies the state of the node that is passed in. It would be better written as:

```
public void AddE(String text, string c)
{
    this.dictionary.Add(c,text);
}
```

... in other words, modifying the state of `this` instead. (It's still odd passing the key *after* the value, and a parameter called `c` provides no hint as to what it's meant to be for, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, understood you perfectly. I managed to solve it like this (added answer to my question).